# Plotting Density Maps with AIS Data

Tags: qgis

I have AIS Data (MMSI, timestamp, latitude, longitude) in Excel files that I want to visualise using density plots/heatmaps, particularly being able to observe which regions have higher number of ships going through them. Since I am completely new in this area, any insight on the initial steps and which tool would be suitable for this would be of great help.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, choose only one GIS software.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should project your points using the lat/long coords in ArcMap or QGIS depending on what you have access to. Once you do this, you should be able to produce any maps necessary in either of the platforms. The link below explains how to produce a points map based on the type of data you have.

http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012745

The next link is an article discussing options for types of maps you may want to create. These are specifically heat style, but you should explore a little and do some research as to what you want to gain from your data and the results.

https://www.gislounge.com/difference-heat-map-hot-spot-map/

Hope this helps somewhat!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link explaining spatial adjustment which had to be done since the lat lons had a different scale and projection when the data was input to a web-based database.

https://sites.temple.edu/psmgis/2017/06/22/using-spatial-adjustment-for-georeferencing-mosquito-point-data-in-arcmap/

Next, if you are using ArcGIS you need to explore the type of density you want.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/differences-between-point-line-and-kernel-density.htm

Finally, if you are using QGIS, there is a heatmap plugin that I have used and it is pretty great and it uses kernel density estimation.

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html